# Trying to get a ID (generated by a trigger/sequence) returned to a variable after a 'Insert into'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I currently have a trigger (with a sequence) set on the VALUE table that auto-generates a new value_id every time a row is inserted into the table. I am trying to return that new value_id (generated by the trigger/sequence) into a variable so that I can use it in an insert into a relationship table later in the proc.

However, when I use the `returning` statement, Oracle returns an error. When I use a traditional insert, the code seems to run/compile just fine.

Do you know what I may be doing wrong? Below is  an abridged version of the code that I wrote:

```
insert into value 
  (value_id, 
   energy_product_id, 
   data_source_id, 
   unit_cd, 
   value_tx, 
   hr
  )
  select null, 
         energy_product_id, 
         data_source_id, 
         unit_cd, 
         value_tx
  from value
  returning value_id into v_value_id;
```

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT: ** Below is the code with the discussed changes. It errors out however:

```
insert into value 
  (value_id, 
   energy_product_id, 
   data_source_id, 
   unit_cd, 
   value_tx, 
   hr
  )
  select (select seq_sample.nextval from dual), 
         energy_product_id, 
         data_source_id, 
         unit_cd, 
         value_tx
  from value
  returning value_id into v_value_id;
```

Comment: What Oracle version? Please post a [mcve]  Are you not using a sequence to generate the value?

Comment: 11.2.0 . I am using a sequence/trigger to generate the value. but i need to return that value into a variable so i can use it in another insert later.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i edited my question , thanks for the heads up. did i make the correct edits as specified in that link?

Comment: So instead of a trigger, get the seq.nextval in the procedure and then you can pass into multiple inserts.

Comment: that would be incorrect because then i would get the next value after the one i inserted . i need that exact value. For example: (1st Table) Value_ID (1) Value_TX(5)    ---     (2nd Table) Value_ID(1) Translation_ID(1) CREATE_DT(sysdate). I need the '1' value_id to show up in both tables/inserts

Comment: No you would not.  Get rid of the trigger, and get the sequence.nextval in the procedure, and use it for your inserts into the two different tables.

Comment: i get an error saying that I can't use a sequence in that insert

Comment: Posting actual command you ran might help. Do edit the initial message and post it there, not in a comment.

Comment: thanks, i posted the actual command/changes that i made to the code

Comment: "returns an error" and "errors out" are not helpful, please include the full error messages in the question. You don't need a subquery to get the sequence value, incidentally. It looks like you will insert multiple rows though, so if `v_value_id` is a scalar variable are you expecting all the new IDs to go into that?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, every single id must be stored and then transferred to a reference table. Also, the error i am getting is: Error(45,33): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALUE_ID" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; .

Comment: The code just won't compile with both 1) that type of insert and 2) my requirement of having to have that id (generated) to be stored in a table via  a 'returning' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can only use the `returning into` clause if your insert has a `values (...)` clause, not if you are using a query.

You could possibly use a collection instead:

```
declare
  type t_rows is table of value_table%rowtype;
  v_rows t_rows;
begin
  select seq_sample.nextval, 
         energy_product_id, 
         data_source_id, 
         unit_cd, 
         value_tx, hr
  bulk collect into v_rows
  from value_table;

  forall i in 1..v_rows.count
    insert into value_table values v_rows(i);

  -- just as debug to see new ID values
  for i in 1..v_rows.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_rows(i).value_id);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If you want to retain the trigger and it overrides any passed-in value - which is normal but this *might* be an exceptional case - then you can use a second collection to get the IDs back, with a bulk-collect returning clause:

```
declare
  type t_rows is table of value_table%rowtype;
  v_rows t_rows;
  type t_ids is table of number;
  v_ids t_ids;
begin
  select null, 
         energy_product_id, 
         data_source_id, 
         unit_cd, 
         value_tx, hr
  bulk collect into v_rows
  from value_table;

  forall i in 1..v_rows.count
    insert into value_table values v_rows(i)
    returning value_id bulk collect into v_ids;

  -- just as debug to see new ID values
  for i in 1..v_ids.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_ids(i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

The indexes for the IDs should correspond with the indexes for the other row data, so you could update the original collection:

```
  for i in 1..v_rows.count loop
    v_rows(i).value_id := v_ids(i);
  end loop;
```

But I'm not sure if that's guaranteed. It seems like it *should* be but I don't recall seeing it documented.

It seems like there should be a more straightforward mechanism to achieve this though...

Answer (score 1):

I had recently posted a question about the working of Insert into returning and I believe that the answer provided by @APC will work  on you case where he mentions that trigger will override https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892580/7071906 assigned value try something like

```
 declare
 select  CURSOR c1 IS
 SELECT 1 val,energy_product_id,data_source_id,unit_cd,value_tx from 
  value
 lrec c1%rowtype;
 ldata c1%rowtype;
id number;
 begin
fetch c1 into lrec

ldata.value_id := lrec.id;
ldata.energy_product_id := lrec.energy_product_id;
ldata.unit_cd := lrec.unit_cd;
ldata.value_tx :=  lrec.value_tx;

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ldata
RETURNING val1 INTO id;
end;
```

[How does Oracle Insert Into work when order of values is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882923/how-does-oracle-insert-into-returning-work-when-order-of-values-is-not-defined)

Comment: thanks, yeah i can get a traditional insert to work but not a insert into select from to return anything... (if that makes sense)

Comment: In that case this stackoverflow thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325033/plsql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-returning-clause-oracle) already points out solution for your question and looks like is exactly what you are asking)

Comment: Ah... thanks @prakriti , it looks like what i'm asking is not possible :(